# Font on links changing when Bootstrap carousel rotates

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, text, carousel

I am having the same issue as this user: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856262/bootstrap-carousel-affects-all-fonts-on-change-slide#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856262/bootstrap-carousel-affects-all-fonts-on-change-slide#_=_)

My working site is: http://bobbyomari.com/clients/charterboost

If you scroll towards the bottom of the page and rotate the testimonial, you'll see that the footer links change their thickness. I tried applying the suggestion in the above link, but it's not working for me.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution: [How to prevent Webkit text rendering change during CSS transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502234/how-to-prevent-webkit-text-rendering-change-during-css-transition/)

Seems forcing GPU acceleration helps with the text rendering.